# What does "lovers of romance" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does it mean lovers with romantic stories, or persons who love romantic stories?

An example in Oxfords Dictionary:

> lovers of sloppy romance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *lover of romance* is simply someone who loves romance. As for what *romance* means, that could refer to a number of things:

- Romantic moments
- Romantic relationships
- Romantic stories
- Romantic operas
- Romantic movies
- Romance books
- The act of courtship

As usual, the meaning depends on context:

> What play did you see last weekend?
>
> Well, I wanted to see *Macbeth*, but my wife is a lover of romance, so we bought tickets for *Twelfth Night* instead.

Or:

> What did you do last weekend?
>
> Well, I wanted to go watch the baseball game, but my wife is a lover of romance, so we ended up going to a nice restaurant instead.

Or even:

> What class did you sign up for last weekend?
>
> Well, I wanted to sign up for Mandarin, but my wife is a lover of Romance languages, so we signed up for French instead.

In that last context, *Romance* gets capitalized – but I still said *lover of romance*.

Answer (score 1):

The example is actually for the adjective [*sloppy*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sloppy) which means *foolishly sentimental.*

> [Lovers] of [sloppy romance] - the lovers of [romance](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ROMANCE) (the relationship), which is foolishly sentimental.

Comment: Does “romance” here mean “books or movies deal with love ”, or "a feeling of love", since the word "romance" can convey several meanings?

Comment: I provided a link there. It's a relationship here in this context. It'll certainly serve as a noun (as following the adjective).

Comment: Would you please paraphrase it by using other words?

Comment: @dennylv You are probably confused as there are two words 'lovers' and 'romance'. Consider a movie titled 'Lovers of Hate' with a tagline - *When love curdles, someone still has to eat it*. I think we can take *Lovers of sloppy romance* that way!

Comment: Can‘t it be "romantic book(or movie) lovers"？Just like "lovers of fashion(or football...)"?

Comment: @dennylv You are right and I thought that way only but since it has an adjective, I turned myself down. However, this could certainly mean that and if it is so, I'll delete this answer!

Comment: It's too short a phrase to say it only has one interpretation. Context is everything! If I'm talking about my teenage girls, filled with angst about their prom date: _The closer we get to April, it's all they talk about; they are just lovers of sloppy romance._ Here I'm talking about dates and flowers and which boys are going to be going steady with which girls – puppy love. But let's move to a chance meeting at the bookstore, where I ask you, "Where's your wife?" _Oh, she's probably over looking at the Harlequins; she's a lover of sloppy romance._ Now, we're talking about a genre of fiction.